# Reposition window using num pad, deprecated?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, numpad

Until now I've been able to move windows around using,
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>[num-pad-key]</kbd>, where 6 would maximize, 8, 6, 2, 4 would move to the sides and 7, 9, 3, 1 would move windows to corners.

I don't why but it seems after an update these were removed (except 6), and now simply print random characters ("A", "B", "C" and so on) instead.

**I've searched but can't find it, can anyone tell me why these were removed and what the new ones are?**

**Edit:** It appears workspace moving keys share the same fate (ie. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + (<kbd>Shift</kbd>) + <kbd>arrow</kbd> keys)

Answer (score 0):

It seems in CompizConfig Settings Manager the "Grid" plugin (from Window Management) has been disabled due to (from  what I can tell) ubuntu using the key now?

To restore the classic functionality for workspace switching you'll want to enable the "Desktop Wall" plugin too.